# Chamar classe construtor

Tags: php, laravel

Na verdade, dessa forma, está muito errado? Não estou entendendo muito a tipagem:

```
class FinanceiroController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * @var ChamadosFinanceirosRepository
     */
    private $chamadosFinanceirosRepository;
    /**
     * @var FinanceiroService
     */
    private $financeiroService;
    /**
     * @var ChamadosFinanceirosService
     */
    private $chamadosFinanceirosService;
    /**
     * @var ChamadosParcelasPagasService
     */
    private $chamadosParcelasPagasService;

    public function __construct(ChamadosFinanceirosRepository $chamadosFinanceirosRepository, FinanceiroService $financeiroService,
                                ChamadosFinanceirosService $chamadosFinanceirosService, ChamadosParcelasPagasService $chamadosParcelasPagasService)
    {
        $this->chamadosFinanceirosRepository = $chamadosFinanceirosRepository;
        $this->financeiroService = $financeiroService;
        $this->chamadosFinanceirosService = $chamadosFinanceirosService;
        $this->chamadosParcelasPagasService = $chamadosParcelasPagasService;
    }
    public function getProvisionamentoPrestador()
    {
        return view('financeiro.provisionamentoPrestador');
    }
    /**
     * @return mixed
     * Busca os chamados financeiros com status_provisionamento_sac finalizado
     */
    public function getBuscaPrestadoresFinanceirosSac()
    {
        return $this->chamadosFinanceirosService->buscaProvisionamentosSac(['status_provisionamento_sac','finalizado']);
    }
    /**
     * @return mixed
     * Busca os chamados financeiros pelo id financeiro
     */
    public function getBuscaPrestadoresFinanceirosSacId()
    {
        //return $this->chamadosFinanceirosService->buscaProvisionamentosSac(['id',\Request::input('id')]);
        return $this->financeiroService->buscaProvisionamentosSac(['id',\Request::input('id')]);
    }

    public function postGravaPagamentoPrestadorChamado()
    {
        return $this->chamadosParcelasPagasService->pagamentoPrestadorChamado(\Request::all());
    }

}
```

Comment: Você não está chamando a classe no construtor. Você está induzindo o tipo que será aceito por parâmetro

Comment: Mais posso trabalhar dessa forma ao invés de instanciar ?

Comment: Não, forçar a tipagem ou não, não vai instanciar o objeto. somente com o new mesmo.

Comment: Mais eu consigo acessar os métodos dessa classe !

Comment: Estamos falando da classe que é dona do construtor ou da classe do parâmetro? Pois ao forçar a tipagem faz sua IDE começar enxergar o que tem naquela variável pois ele tem certeza qual vai ser a classe dela, dai ele disponibiliza pra ti os métodos.

Comment: Se você estiver falando do $this->classe, você tem que instanciar o objeto antes de passar por parâmetro.

Comment: Se eu fuzer assim funciona $this->classe->método()

Answer (score 2):

Nesse caso você está forçando a tipagem do parametro para uma classe do tipo "Classe".

A vantagem é que você garante o tipo de dados e pode trabalhar melhor com o polimorfismo e garantir a integridade do sistema.

A desvantagem é que se você por algum motivo quiser passar outro tipo de dado vai precisar re-escrever o método.
Mas essa desvantagem na verdade é uma má estruturação do código pois essa é a melhor maneira de trabalhar e escrever um código limpo e claro.

Answer (score 1):

Você não está chamando a classe no construtor. Você está induzindo o tipo que será aceito por parâmetro.

Veja para que serve a sua declaração:

```
class X {

   private $classe;

    public  function __construct(Classe $classe)
    {
           $this->classe = $classe;
    }
}
```

Nesse caso, você está dizendo que somente a instância de `Classe` será aceita por parâmetro no construtor.

Veja:

```
 new X(new Classe);
```

Se você tentar passar um outro valor qualquer, isso gerará um erro:

```
new X(1);
```

Saída:

> X::__construct() must be an instance of Classe, integer given.

Answer (score 0):

Para que a classe **FinanceiroController** seja instanciada, ela precisa receber 4 parâmetros em seu construtor, o tipo que é induzido é o nome das classes que você precisa utilizar, sendo uma delas é do tipo repositório e as outras três do tipo de serviços. Geralmente essas classes são ramificadas dentro do seu projeto `/entity/entities/` e `/service/services/`.

Para entender melhor o conceito, sugiro que você procure estudar **Design Patterns** e **Strategy Patterns**.

Se já está acostumado com inglês, aqui tem um site muito bom:
https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/strategy

Se prefere algo em português, tem esse site também que é excelente:
http://br.phptherightway.com/pages/Design-Patterns.html

Para entender esse tipo de indução, na documentação do PHP tem mais informações:
http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.typehinting.php

Comment: Isso eu entendo, o que não entendo é que se eu consigo acessar os métodos da classe tipando ela dessa forma pra que instanciar ?